# What should I Improve from my Neural Network Model (Logistic Regression)

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, keras, tensorflow, logistic-regression

### Initial Information

I built a Neural Network Model (**Logistic Regression**) to classify Lung Cancer based on the patient's (user) symptoms

My dataset is kind of small (only about **276 data**)

Here is the **illustration for my dataset**:

```
data.head()
```

| GENDER | AGE | SMOKING | YELLOW_FINGERS | ANXIETY | PEER_PRESSURE | CHRONIC DISEASE | FATIGUE | ALLERGY | WHEEZING | ALCOHOL CONSUMING | COUGHING | SHORTNESS OF BREATH | SWALLOWING DIFFICULTY | CHEST PAIN | LUNG_CANCER |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| M | 69 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | YES |
| M | 74 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 2 | YES |
| F | 59 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 1 | 2 | NO |
| M | 63 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 2 | NO |

Here's how I **preprocessing** the dataset:

1. I drop the duplicate data
2. I encode the [GENDER] and [LUNG CANCER] value
3. I change the 2,1 value to 1,0
4. I scale the age feature using StandardScaler()
5. I resample the training set using RandomOverSampler().fit_resample

Here's my **Neural Network Model**:

```
model = Sequential(
    [
        Dense(3, activation = 'sigmoid', input_shape=[15]),
        Dense(1, activation = 'sigmoid'),
    ])

model.compile(
loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(),
optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.01),
metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, 
                        epochs=50, batch_size=16,
                        validation_split=0.2, 
                        shuffle=True)
```

Here's the **Training Result**:

[image: Model Accuracy]
[image: Model Loss]

Here's the **test result**:

```
test_loss, test_acc = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test)
print("Test loss:", test_loss)
print("Test accuracy:", test_acc)

3/3 [==============================] - 0s 4ms/step - loss: 0.1746 - accuracy: 0.9420

Test loss: 0.17462675273418427 Test accuracy: 0.9420289993286133
```

Here's the **confusion matrix** and **classification report**:
[image: Confusion Matrix]

```
                precision    recall  f1-score   support

           0       0.98      0.95      0.97        60
           1       0.73      0.89      0.80         9

    accuracy                           0.94        69
   macro avg       0.86      0.92      0.88        69
weighted avg       0.95      0.94      0.94        69
```

**My QUESTION:**

- Is my model result (accuracy) good enough considering I want to build a Cancer Detection app using this model?
- If my model result (accuracy) is not good enough, how could I improve this model? What parameter should I tweak or maybe should I reduce or add the Neural layer?

**Note:** Please enlighten me, I'm kind of new to Machine Learning :)

Comment: Why don't you leave the model train for a longer time? From the loss curves it seems there's still room for improvement

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I will try it :)

Answer (score 1):

1. It depends on the application. This is more of a business than technical question. Also, are you sure accuracy is a good metric for your application?
2. Get more data, and try more different models; consider ensembling.

Do not spend more time to train or add more layers; it is already overfitting. Won't do you any good.

Comment: Hmm now that you said, I think Recall is a more suitable metric for my application.

Thank you for the advice :)

Comment: Just Recall? It can get 100% Recall by guessing everyone has cancer.

Comment: Hmm, precision too maybe? But I think recall metrics is a little bit more important than precision (because to avoid too many False Negative) for Cancer Detection (considering it's a rare disease)

Comment: May I ask something again?

Should I split my training data (to have validation data) before resampling my training data? or It's okay to resample my training data first an then split it to have validation data?

Comment: I'd say before resampling, to make sure both test and validation set follow exactly same distribution as where they come from. But not 100% certain.